# Change IP adress via web interface

Tags: linux, ip, web

How do I go about changing the IP address manually on a device running Linux(debian) via an web interface?
A script which will prompt for for IP change.
I have a web server running PHP on it.
Not sure what's needed for this in order to provide more details.
I am particularly interested on changing the IP remotely via web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP or any other server-side code is out of scope for SuperUser and would be a better fit for StackOverflow, I'm assuming you just want to know the commands to run on Linux to control the IP address.

First, you need to identify which network interface you want to be dealing with.
`ip link` displays all interfaces. `lo` is not the one you want. The one you want probably looks something like `enp9s0` for Ethernet (or possibly `eth0`), and for Wifi it might start with `wlu`.

Once you have that identified, `ip addr` is the tool to set, change, or remove IP addresses.

`ip addr add 192.168.0.10/24 dev <yourinterface>` will add the address.
`ip addr del 192.168.0.10/24 dev <yourinterface>` will remove the specified address.
`ip addr show dev <yourinterface>` will list them, though it is confusingly laid out.

Note, you can have multiple IP addresses on one interface if you wish.

Manual page for the `ip` command:
https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need to find a way to change the IP address via a web browser. IP has to be static and also permanent change. The commands above will change the IP but temporarily until next reboot. I can do the IP change via command line. I know the command line options and /etc/network/interfaces. Wired interface I'm interested but any will do.

Comment: @my8y https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-a-static-ip-address-on-debian-linux